# Permutation nth term

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

I was working on a proof and I needed to know the nth term of the permutation's expansion
meaning that: we all know that $^mP_n=m(m-1)(m-2)...(m-n+1)$
so if I want the $n^{th}$ term of that series, how should I get it?

Comment: what do you mean by nth term ?

Comment: if I want to put the expansion as a summation of terms generally, like (sigma(n),n from 0 to 3 =0+1+2+3)
so mPn=sigme(what?)

Comment: you mean m is fixed ? could you take small values and give an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: m is unknown
$^mP_3=m(m-1)(m-2)=m^{3}-3m^{2}+2m$
so $^mP_n=?$ as a summation of terms, like $am^{n}+bm^{n-1}+...$

Answer (score 0):

A notation for $_mP_n$ is $m^{\underline{n}}$, where that underlined power is called a "falling power."

The coefficients you want are called Stirling Numbers of the first kind; the notation is 
$$
m^{\underline{n}} = \sum_k (-1)^{n-k}\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right] m^k
$$

Sitrling numbers of the first kind count the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects into $k$ cycles. They satisfy the recurrence
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right] = (n-1)\left[ \begin{array}{c} n-1 \\ k \end{array}\right] + \left[ \begin{array}{c} n-1 \\ k-1 \end{array}\right]
$$ with 
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ p \end{array}\right] = 0$$
for $p>n$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] = 1$.
This lets you form a sort of "Sitrlings triangle: (like a Pascal triangle) out of them.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but I don't quite understand how to compute $\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right]$
also how can I write maths on this site? I'm kinda new here

Comment: There is no simple closed form for Stirling numbers in terms of factorials, binomial coefficients, and simple powers. $\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$ is zero unless $n=0$, in which case it is $1$. $\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ 1 \end{array}\right] = (n-1)!$ and $\left[ \begin{array}{c} n \\ 2\end{array}\right] = (n-1)! H_{n-1}$ where $H_k$ is the sum of the reciprocals of integers up to $k$. A good reference is chapter 6.1 of Knuth's Concrete Mathematics.